# Reegex to replace 'char buf[10];'

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to implement a `Regex` in order to be able to match something like this:

```
char buffer[10];
```

- where buffer can be replaced by any possible variable name
- and 10 can be replaced by any integer.

I have tried the following but are not working:

- `@"char(?:[a-z][a-z]+)\[\d+\];"`
- `@"char(?:[a-z][a-z]+)\\[\\d+\\];"`
- `@"char (?:[a-z][a-z]+)\[\d+\];"`
- `@"char \\w)\[\d+\];"`

Kindly advice, or perhaps point out what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: `char [a-zA-Z]+\[\d+\];` i've found http://www.regexr.com/ to be helpful

Comment: You want to extract these too?

Comment: @austinwernli  thank you, but that is not working.

Comment: How are you using it that it is not working?

Comment: A variable name can also contain numbers just not the first char

Comment: _Why_ do you want this?

Comment: @Code what better way to manipulate buffers in your c code? :) On the serious note I agree, this smells like something very unsafe.

Comment: @bokibeg yeah there are plenty of C# parsers out there. You don't want to do that using regular expressions. But hey, the answerers get their points and the asker gets to check off their worksheet as it gives a positive for their one test case, so who am I to complain.

Comment: I'm building my own Lexical Analyser for a school project, and am tokenizing using Regex.  There's really nothing unsafe going on hehe  Thank you all for your answers and comments :) I greatly appriciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
char (?=\w+\[)[^\[]+\[\d+\];
```

or simply:

```
char \w+\[\d+\];
```

Comment: It is not a reliable solution, for example it matches with: "char aaa bbb ccc [234];"

Answer (score 1):

`char (?<varname>\w+)\[(?<size>\d+)\]`

It gives you two groups so you can play with it as you like.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
^char (?i)(?<varName>[a-z_][a-z_\d]+)\[(?<size>0|([0-9]\d+))\];$
```

It matches with string that contains **valid** variable name and non-negative integer.